# How to use store image URL in Email Templates

Tags: magento-2.1, email

I have multiple stores and want to change Store Logo in Email templates specific to the store.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a day, I found a simple way to use store specific logo URL in your custom email templates.

> Step1: First You need to create a logo.phtml file in

```
app/code/<namespace>/<theme>/view/frontend/templates/
```

> Include below single line code in your logo.phtml file, this will return store logo source URL

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>
```

> Step2: Now you can use below code directly into your custom email template file:

```
<img src="{{block class='Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Header\\Logo' template='<namespace>_<theme>::logo.phtml'}}" alt="Store Specific Logo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to below **setting**

`Content > Design > Configuration`

**Edit** the store view you want to edit store logo for from the grid.

You will find the last option **Transactional Emails** where you can upload your logo for each store views.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that I have tried but successfully loaded image but in email templates, it is using default Magento image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change logo as per store in email template

```
Admin >> Content >> Design >> Configuration >> Edit (Specific Store) >> Transaction Email.
```

Store specific uploaded logo will display as per store email template.

Comment: Thanks, We have this option but it's not working. If we have store logo then why we need to include another logo for email logo.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a code like this in you code template

```
<img src="{{view url='Magento_Email/logo.png'}}" alt="{{trans 'your alt'}}" width="xxx" height="yyy" />
```

and put you image in

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/theme-name/Magento_Email/web/logo.png
```

You can put your image in the frontend module relative to the image you want to keep modularity ;)

In BO :

```
Marketing > email templates > add a template > select the template you want > load it > edit the code, set-up it and save it
```